# What is the default TimeZone in AppVeyor?

Tags: javascript, c#, timezone, appveyor

As per title, what is the default TimeZone in AppVeyor?

I've tried asking Google about it... nothing found

Comment: Appveyor has good support, why not ask them directly?

Comment: Timezone defaults are normally the local computer settings.

Comment: @jdweng ok, but what's the default value on AppVeyor?

Comment: My guess is UTC - or at least it should be.  Try putting a "tzutil.exe /g" in your build script and see.

Comment: Has said by @RonBeyer AppVeyor has a good support look this search result http://help.appveyor.com/search?q=timezone&t=d&recommend=1 .

Comment: In particular, the final answer (#6) of [this question](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/2391-setting-build-worker-time-zone#comment_37254744) is a good approach if you're just trying to get a timestamp in a specific time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should rely on time zone currently set on build workers, but you should configure your own required time zone. It could be easily done with `tzutil` utility, for example in `appveyor.yml`:

```
init: 
- tzutil /s "Mountain Standard Time"
```

You can list all available zones with `tzutil /l` command.

Comment: Careful, time zone settings on Windows are system-wide.  Chances are there are other processes on the same machine.  If the environment is isolated properly, you won't be able to do this.  Really, if the server has to be set to any specific time zone, then that's an issue unto itself. The build script (or whatever it does) should rely only on UTC.

Comment: @MattJohnson ok, so what do you suggest?

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini - Well, you haven't said *why* you want to change the time zone, so its difficult to suggest anything in particular.  Perhaps you could edit your question to show code where you are dependent on the system time zone.  Then I can answer appropriately.  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson I want to change the timezone because I'm doing some tests which rely on it. I don't want to run tests with some random input (i.e. the current system timezone) so I want to set it before the tests. My local test environment and the appveyor test environment doesn't have the same timezone

Comment: Well, as long as Appveyor's isolation is as pristine as they advertise on their home page, then using `tzutil` to set the time zone is fine (+1 to Fedor). But I'd advise you to consider that it may be safer to change the code and tests so they do not rely on it.  For example, if your app is .NET and your code or test includes a `DateTime.Now` call, then change it to `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtct(DateTime.UtcNow, "Mountain Standard Time")`.  Similar techniques apply to other environments as well.

Answer (score 0):

Their crontab entries for scheduled builds use UTC, so I would guess that's what they use overall.